# CakePHP 1.3 - Send non-form data to controller with js helper

Tags: ajax, jquery, cakephp-1.3

I have a ul of dynamic buttons in my view that appears like the following:

```
<ul id="dashboard_list">
  <li id="id_100" class="btn btn-primary">
    <a id="id_100" href="/plugin_name/controller_name/action_name/100">Default View</a>
  </li>
  <li id="id_200" class="btn btn-primary">
    <a id="id_200" href="/plugin_name/controller_name/action_name/200">Second View</a>
  </li>
  <li id="id_300" class="btn btn-primary">
     <a id="id_300" href="/plugin_name/controller_name/action_name/300">Third View</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The above links are created using the JSHelper as follows:

```
echo $this->Html->link($view->name, '/plugin_name/controller_name/action_name/'. $view->id, array('class' => 'ajax-link', 'id'=> $view->id));
```

I'm using the script below that I found while researching:

```
// onClick function
function onClick(){
    $('#view_container').load($(this).attr('href'), onSuccess); 
    return false;
}

// activate ajax links to call the onClick function
$('.ajax-link').live('click', onClick);

// onSuccess-callback function
function onSuccess(){}
```

Now, in my controller / action im doing a simple check for data as follows:

```
function actionName() {
    if ($this->data != null) {
        die('We has data!');
    }
    else
    {
        die('We has no data.');
    }
}
```

My #view_container element updates properly with "We has no data" on every click.  So, I'm obviously not communicating the link's view id number (data) between the view and the controller.

Can anyone offer some direction on how to implement this functionality in CakePHP 1.3 to access the selected id (variable) in the controller?  I mostly seem to find form submission examples (or just dead links), and I unfortunately don't have the option to upgrade cakePHP.

FYI: The proper helpers, scripts and the js->writeBuffer are being included.

Thank you for any responses in advance!

Comment: Here's my solution so far which probably doesnt follow the cakePHP methodology, so if you have a more "cakey" way to achieve this then feel free to respond. I would be interested in learning alt methods to this.  
Since I was passing the view_id to the URL in the link:  
`href="/plugin_name/controller_name/action_name/300"`  
I just adjusted the action to grab the id from the URL as $view_id:  
`function actionName($view_id) { if ($view_id != null) { die('We has data!'); } else { die('We has no data.'); } }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewrite your function as follows:

```
function actionName($id) {
    debug($id);
    if ($this->data != null) {
        die('We has data!');
    }
    else
    {
        die('We has no data.');
    }
}
```

If you need to do more than one variable in the URL ex:

```
href="/plugin_name/controller_name/action_name/300/yellow/bannana"
```

Then your function would look like:

```
function actionName($id,$color,$fruit) {
}
```

Comment: The debug($id) returns the value, but the value isn't accessible via $this->data. I can test for if($id != null) and get the "We has data!" result, but I'm not sure why I can't access the value using cakes standard method.  Thanks!

Comment: because $this->data is used to get information to the same view, but your redirecting to a different URL.  Pages don't have data when they load.

You could easily do that with a drop down and a regular submit button, and the drop down would appear in $this->data OR the page here has some more information on mutliple buttons and detecting which is clicked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10172522/cakephp-2-0-determine-which-submit-button-has-been-clicked

Comment: I see, thanks.  I had actually concluded that this was unique because it wasn't a form, but I didn't really consider using multiple submit buttons.  My challenge is finding the right method for 1.3 because I'm stuck using that version.